# Is it safe to use a signed message as a private encryption key?

Tags: encryption

Can I safely use a signature as a private key for the purposes of encryption?

```
let sig = sign("email", "originalSecretKey");

encrypt(
  "foobar@example.org", 
  "someNonce", 
  "theirPublicKey", 
  sig // <--- Use signature as new private key?
);
```

I'm looking for a way to "scope" the originalSecretKey. Let the user safely keep one secret key, and deterministically generate new ones for each type of data (email, medical records, SSN, etc) by signing a message.

This lets one selectively give information to applications that require it, without revealing the rest.

Comment: Use HKDF-Expand https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5869#section-2.3

Answer (score 1):

> Let the user safely keep one secret key, and deterministically generate new ones for each type of data

As knaccc said in a comment, you can use [HKDF](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5869#section-2.3) for this. You could also use personalization hashes from [BLAKE2](https://www.blake2.net/blake2.pdf) or any keyed hash function. You should not be using public key cryptography for this.

For HKDF-Expand, you specify a secret key `PRK`, a custom value `info`, and a length `L`:

```
   HKDF-Expand(PRK, info, L) -> OKM

   Options:
      Hash     a hash function; HashLen denotes the length of the
               hash function output in octets

   Inputs:
      PRK      a pseudorandom key of at least HashLen octets
               (usually, the output from the extract step)
      info     optional context and application specific information
               (can be a zero-length string)
      L        length of output keying material in octets
               (<= 255*HashLen)

   Output:
      OKM      output keying material (of L octets)
```

The `info` value is described in more detail in section 3.2 of the RFC:

```
   While the 'info' value is optional in the definition of HKDF, it is
   often of great importance in applications.  Its main objective is to
   bind the derived key material to application- and context-specific
   information.  For example, 'info' may contain a protocol number,
   algorithm identifiers, user identities, etc.  In particular, it may
   prevent the derivation of the same keying material for different
   contexts (when the same input key material (IKM) is used in such
   different contexts).  It may also accommodate additional inputs to
   the key expansion part, if so desired (e.g., an application may want
   to bind the key material to its length L, thus making L part of the
   'info' field).  There is one technical requirement from 'info': it
   should be independent of the input key material value IKM.
```

Comment: "You should not be using public key cryptography for this." Why not? What if I don't have access to the actual encryption key (such as in a crypto wallet), and only have access to the ability to produce a signature?